# ASP.Net MVC 4 & Jquery Select option

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Question:
Im building a dynamic list of products which every product contains a "Product Type", im looping through each product but I need to set the selected option for an existing product

```
$.each(products.All(), function(index, product) {
for(p in productList) {
                $( "#"+product.itemId+"_type" ).append($("<option/>", {
                    value: productList[g].value,
                    text: productList[g].label,
//Need to add something like if(productList[g].value == p.typeId) selected:true
                }));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a SelectList as you specified you are using ASP.Net MVC 4

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Two constructors gives you the possibility of setting the selected value. Anyway

you could to this

```
$("<option/>").attr("selected", "selected");
```

or

```
    $.each(products.All(), function(index, product) {
    for(p in productList) {

    // declare here a variable selectedValue

    if(productList[g].value == p.typeId){

    // set here a variable selectedValue 
    }
    else {
    // set here a variable selectedValue 
    }



                $( "#"+product.itemId+"_type" ).append($("<option/>", {
                    value: productList[g].value,
                    text: productList[g].label,
                    selected: selectedValue,
                }));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.each(products.All(), function(index, product) {
     var select = document.getElementById("YourSelect");
             for(p in productList) 
               {
                   var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent =productList[g].label;
                    el.value = productList[g].value;
                    if(productList[g].value == p.typeId)
                     {
                      el.selected = true;
                     }
                    select.appendChild(el);

               }
   });
</script>
```